# DocuSign remembers signature. Want to turn that feature off

Tags: docusignapi

It appears docusign remembers the adopted signature for a certain email, regardless of, if they are a user or docusign member. Is there any way to turn off that feature?

In other words, we want our users to never have an adopted signature on file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an option in Preferences -> Features -> Signature Adoption screen that controls whether users can adopt their signature or not, shown here:

[image: Signature Adoption Settings]

However this feature might not be enabled by default in your demo account.  If it's not, you'll have to contact your Account Manager who can then turn it on for you.  It's possible they will have to enable two options for your account - first you'll need access to the Signature Adoption settings if you don't have it already, then there's an option called "Disable Style Signature" which you also need checked on your account.

If you do not have an account manager yet please respond to the one or two emails you would have automatically received after account creation.  You can also reach out to

```
service@docusign.com
```

for support and any other help you may need with accounts.

Comment: I can't find the "Preferences -> Features -> Signature Adoption" menu

Comment: The only thing that looks related is "Authenticate on return access to envelope". Is that the setting?

Comment: Sorry for delay, you must be using the new UI which doesn't have access to the advanced console settings yet.  Try switch to the CLassic web view in the Console then you will see the screen I'm talking about...