# Recipient needs to adopt a new signature every time he needs to sign a document

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign with my web application. Whenever I try to sign in the document, the first time I am asked for adopting a signature. From next time onwards, docusign uses the same saved signatire every time even if I need to sign a new document. I need a feature where the recipient should be asked to adopt and sign everytime he visits a new document. But this is not happening. Is there any way we can do it? If not, do we have an option in DocuSign recipient view where the recipient can select a new signature at his will?

The querstion in [DocuSign remembers signature. Want to turn that feature off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240991/docusign-remembers-signature-want-to-turn-that-feature-off)
is similar to mine. I tried the answers mentioned in the post but it did not help.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using captive recipients and embedded signing.  In this scenario, the signer is captive to your application.  So, if you define a recipient a 2nd time using the same name, email and client user ID, DocuSign will use the signature the recipient adopted the first time around.

Two ways around this.

First, make the client user ID random.  This way, the recipient is always unique and will always adopt a new signature.

Second, delete the signers signature from your account after the envelope is completed.  This way, they would have to adopt again even if you use the same client user id.

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely an option for this. Unfortunately I don't know which one it is.

Plus it might be one of the account options that is set by DocuSign Customer Service.

If you're working with a salesrep, ask him or her to have the setting updated for your developer account.

If you simply want to ensure (for your demos and development) that the signer will always be asked to adopt a signature, you can do that by always using a new {name, email} tuple.

Eg if you send a doc to {Joe Signer, joe@signer.com} the first time, send to {Joe A. Signer, joe@signer.com} the second time.

I use this technique during demos to ensure that the demonstration will include the signature adoption step.